# Stubbing Meteor `user` and `userId` using `sinon-ts`

Tags: typescript, meteor, sinon

I would like to stub `user` and `userId` using `sinon-ts` so I can test my server side code that gets results from the database.

If I use plain `sinon` I can stub `user` and `userId` correctly and the test passes. Although it passes `Webstorm` shows errors where the `returns` method doesn't exist etc so I don't think it is playing well with `Typescript`.

**sinon - Passes**

```
import {Factory} from 'meteor/dburles:factory';
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {resetDatabase} from 'meteor/xolvio:cleaner';
import {GiftListCollectionManager} from "../imports/api/collections/GiftListCollection";
import User = Meteor.User;
import { sinon } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:sinon';

describe("Test", function () {
    beforeEach(() => {
        resetDatabase();
        Factory.define('user', Meteor.users, {

        });
        currentUser = Factory.create('user');
        sinon.stub(Meteor, 'user');

        Meteor.user.returns(currentUser);

        sinon.stub(Meteor, 'userId');

        Meteor.userId.returns(currentUser._id);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        Meteor.user.restore();
        Meteor.userId.restore();
        resetDatabase();
    });

    it("Gets giftlists based on Meteor.userId()", () => {
        console.log("Gift lists")
        console.log(GiftListCollectionManager.getInstance().getGiftLists());
    })
}
```

I decided to give `sinon-ts` a try so I can get no syntax errors shown. I can't seem to get it to stub `user` and `userId` correctly.

**sinon-ts - Failing**

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {resetDatabase} from 'meteor/xolvio:cleaner';
import {GiftListCollectionManager} from "../imports/api/collections/GiftListCollection";

import * as sinon from "ts-sinon";

describe("Test", function () {

    let currentUser;

    beforeEach(() => {
        resetDatabase();
        Factory.define('user', Meteor.users, {

        });
        currentUser = Factory.create('user');

        const userStub = sinon.stubObject(Meteor);

        userStub.user.returns(currentUser);

        const userIdStub = sinon.stubObject(Meteor);

        userIdStub.userId.returns(currentUser._id);
    });


    it("Gets giftlists based on Meteor.userId()", () => {
        console.log("Gift lists")
        console.log(GiftListCollectionManager.getInstance().getGiftLists());
    })
});
```

**Error**

```
I20210322-09:45:44.170(0)?      Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls or publications.
I20210322-09:45:44.170(0)?       at AccountsServer.userId (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:117:13)
I20210322-09:45:44.171(0)?       at Object.Meteor.userId (packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js:339:32)
I20210322-09:45:44.171(0)?       at GiftListCollectionManager.getGiftLists (imports/api/collections/GiftListCollection.ts:32:61)
I20210322-09:45:44.171(0)?       at Test.<anonymous> (tests/main.ts:66:61)
I20210322-09:45:44.171(0)?       at run (packages/meteortesting:mocha-core/server.js:36:29)
I20210322-09:45:44.171(0)?       at Context.wrappedFunction (packages/meteortesting:mocha-core/server.js:65:33)
```

I've spent a lot of time looking around and can't find anything on people stubbing Meteor `user` and `userId` using `sinon-ts`.

What is the correct method of achieving the same results?

**Update**

Using callsFake throws an exception

```
import sinon = require('sinon');
sinon.stub(Meteor, 'user').callsFake(() => currentUser);
sinon.stub(Meteor, 'userId').callsFake(() => currentUser._id);
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: sinon.stub(...).callsFake is not a function
at Hook.<anonymous> (tests/main.ts:19:36)
at run (packages/meteortesting:mocha- core/server.js:36:29)
```

Comment: The error indicates, that the function is not stubbed, because the method/publication invocation check is part of both of `Meteor.userId` and `Meteor.user`. Do you need to use `sinon.stubObject` with `sinon-ts`? Can't you stub the default way `sinon.stub(Meteor, 'user').callsFake(() => currentUser)` ? I use the plain npm sinon package and my user stubs work with this kind of pattern.

Comment: If I use callsFake I get an exception as the function isn't found. I can use `returns` but that is highlighted as a syntax error which is likely to do with it being Typescript and not  Javascript. I've updated the question.

Comment: I just checked the docs and you should be able [to access the underlying original sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-sinon#sinon-methods) via `sinon.default`, assuming your current import structure `* as sinon`. Does ist run with `sinon.default.stub(Meteor, 'user').callsFake(() => currentUser)` then?

Comment: That worked thanks! I also changed calling `Meteor.user.restore` to `userStub.restore`. Would you like to answer the question and I'll accept it?

Comment: If you'd prefer me to answer it I'm more than happy to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that `sinon-ts` implements "extensions" around sinon to make it work better with TypeScript but it still supports the "default" sinon behaviour.

The [function stubs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v9.2.4/stubs/) are known to work with `Meteor.user()` and `Meteor.userId()` and can be access via

```js
import sinon, { stubInterface } from "ts-sinon";

const functionStub = sinon.stub();
```

or via

```js
import * as tsSinon from "ts-sinon"

const functionStub = tsSinon.default.stub();
```

Applying this scheme to your current code would result in the following code, that is expected to work with Meteor's user functions:

```js
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import * as sinon from "ts-sinon";
// ... other imports

describe("Test", function () {
    let currentUser;

    beforeEach(() => {
        resetDatabase();
        Factory.define('user', Meteor.users, {

        });
        currentUser = Factory.create('user');

        sinon.default.stub(Meteor, 'user').callsFake(() => currentUser);
        sinon.default.stub(Meteor, 'userId').callsFake(() => currentUser._id);
    });

    // ... test units
});
```

References:

https://github.com/ttarnowski/ts-sinon#sinon-methods

https://sinonjs.org/releases/v9.2.4/stubs/